# Can someone please tell me how I can show a button after the end of a game?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a page where the information (buttons) are hidden and you need to play a puzzle so information will be shown. I made the puzzle and I don't know how to show buttons right after the game over, any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your HTML :

```
<button id="showMeAfterGameEnds">Play Again?</button>
```

using jQuery :

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#showMeAfterGameEnds').hide();   
    function game(){ 
        //some game code
    
        //at game exit
        showHiddenButtons()
    }
    
    function showHiddenButtons() {
        $('#showMeAfterGameEnds').show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need jQuery, but it makes it much easier:

```
window.onload = function() {
    $("button.showAtEnd").hide();
};
```

At the end, to show it, you can do:

```
$("button.showAtEnd").show();
```